# ClientResponseError on edit_message coroutine after around 1234 edits

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have setup a bot to delete thousands upon thousands of messages, it's around 20,000 messages, my code works and is deleting messages, I also have a message that's constantly being edited to tell me how many messages have been deleted out of total, which also works but after a while I get a ClientResponseError exception from that line and it halts my message deleting loop, why is this happening? and can I just use a `try except` and then `pass` so my loop doesn't halt? I'm not exactly sure what that exception even is, the documentation doesn't have anything on it

Code:

```
counter = 0
begin, end = around_month(month, year)
tmsg = await Client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'Progress: 0/' + str(number))
estimate = number * 1.5
estimate = estimate / 60
estimate = estimate / 60
estimate = round(estimate, 2)
await Client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'Estimated time: ' + str(estimate) + 'hours')
async for x in Client.logs_from(channelid, limit = number, after=begin, before=end):
    counter += 1
    await Client.edit_message(tmsg, 'Progress: ' + str(counter) + '/' + str(number))
    await Client.delete_message(x)
    await asyncio.sleep(1.5)
await Client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'Operation completed! ' + 'Cleared: ' + str(counter) + ' items')
```

Comment: Could you post the entire traceback for the error?  Catching and ignoring the error would be a totally valid way of handling this.  Try putting a `print` in the except block and see if this happens randomly, or if all attempts to edit the message start failing at a certain point.

Comment: There you go: https://pastebin.com/Sm3kBLSF, thank you very much for your reply

Comment: Does this happen consistently?  The nested error is `ServerDisconnectedError`, which seems to indicate that you're dropping the connection to the server.  Are you doing any blocking operation that could be interfering with this one?

Comment: It does happen consistently. As I said i'm deleting around 20,000 messages, so it's a loop that takes around 8 hours to complete with asyncio set to sleep for 1.5 seconds. But that's the only thing I have. I had issues with bots disconnecting randomly in the past, but I have `reconnection=True` on `client.run`

Comment: Hmm.  Try deleting that message and sending a new one every 1000 deleted messages?  Alternatively, you could switch to the rewrite branch and try to use [`TextChannel.purge`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge).

Comment: I have considered switching to the rewrite branch, I did take a look at an example and it seemed way too much trouble for what im trying to do, ill try to catch the exception and ignore it and see what happens